# Can Sysinternal commands be ran from within PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sysinternals

I am a desktop support person and trying learn both `Sysinternal`s and `PowerShell`. I have grown to understand the power of both and now I am asking if the `sysinternals` commands can run within `powershell`. I have tried a few, but they do not seem to get along well. I also understand `PowerShell` much better than `DOS`. The dos window opens then closes when I run a `sysinternals` command from `PowerShell`, and I notice that there are many `PowerShell` commands that do a similar job as the `sysinternals` commands. There are still many `sysinternals` commands that are killer good to know and use, I would just like to execute them from the `PowerShell ISE` console, can that be done?

Comment: The short answer is yes... You should be more specific if you need help with a particular problem.

Comment: One of the PowerShell MVPs did an article on this recently: http://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/2014/06/scraping-sysinternals/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are looking for something in specific, but if you are trying to get the output of the sysinternal commands in powershell then yes, since powershell's philosophy is to  process objects and syinternal commands will get you text. Using a start-process with redirected outputs can help if you have problems with parsing the data live.

Many of the sysinternal utilities are graphical in nature, procmon is the only one I have automated so far but others can be worked out as well however only to capture information. You may write a sysinternals powershell module and automate the launches from the ISE console.